# PhoneGap/Cordova and native Android/iOS backend

Tags: java, android, ios, cordova, swift

Is it possible to create an application, where Apache Cordova framework would be used just for UI and on the backend it would be usual Android/iOS app, written in Java/Swift? Is it possible with Cordova to reuse existing libraries, designed for use in Java/Swift/Objective C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova *is* the "backend" as you describe it. It uses plugins written in Java, Objective-C, and other languages to map underlying device APIs into Javascript objects accessible to custom applications written in HTML/Javascript/CSS. You can wrap other libraries in your own plugins to provide custom functionality not covered by the current Cordova framework.

Cordova doesn't include a UI framework. Developers may build apps with Ionic, Angular, JQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch, et cetera or create their own Javascript solution, then layer that in front of Cordova.